# Executable files obfuscated with different encryptors

Tags: dll

I would like to test (and validate) an application that analyses executable files obfuscated with UPX, ASProtect, PECompact, etc... Does someone knows a place where I can find (dummy) samples apps obfuscated with different algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

Many software use packers to compress/obfuscate their binaries. However, instead of searching for such already obfuscated applications, I think you can download packers and obfuscate some application by yourself. You can then use these packed binaries for testing/validating PE analyzer. Some of the well known packers are:
http://upx.sourceforge.net/ 
http://www.bitsum.com/pecompact.php 
http://www.aspack.com/asprotect.html

Comment: Thanks. I know I can use and 'validate' my tool that analyzes packers. However, I wanted to know whether a kind of list of packers and an equivalent list of encrypted PE files exist. Somehow something like "notepad.exe" encrypted with all of these. Like using vectors to test standard encrpyption and decryption algorithms.